# How do you view a version of Chrome saved on mac time machine

Tags: search, google-chrome

I visited a very important website on April 18th but I do not remember the name of it.  I know I visited on April 18th because I have a file that I got from that website and it was created on April 18th.   This website could crawl through the internet and pick out a huge number of sentence with a specific word or phrase and organize them into an easy to use format.  This website is absolutely critical for my linguistics research.  My chrome history only goes back to May 8th so I can't find it that way.  However I have time machine back ups to the dates in question.  I looked at my files from time machine and I was only able to find a file in the chrome default folder that said 'history provider cache', not 'history'.  I was thinking maybe I could log out of the admin on my mac and log into another user and use the old Chrome files for that user.  I tried this but it looks like all of the files for Chrome are stored on one hard driver and the other users all use the same files.  I really do not want to erase my current Chrome settings but would rather upload my historic settings to another Chrome browser that won't affect my current Chrome browser.

Also, I'm aware of the solution of looking at Google's my activity.  That solution takes too long, it takes me about 1 hour to go through 3 days of activity on Google Chrome's my activity.

Answer (score 1):

This does not answer your exact question but is a solution to the problem that you face.

1. Navigate to https://myactivity.google.com/myactivity.
2. Ensure that you are logged in to the Google account used on April 18.
3. Click **Filter by date & product**.
4. In the **Before** and **After** fields, enter **April 18**.

   [image: Picture: Google Activity: Filter by date]
5. Click the **Search** button and you will be shown the activity on that day.

If you know the time of day you found the website, you can also locate the time of the search to the minute.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but at the end of my post I addressed that solution: Also, I'm aware of the solution of looking at Google's my activity. That solution takes too long, it takes me about 1 hour to go through 3 days of activity on Google Chrome's my activity.

Comment: If you filter to that one day and (if you remember) to the time of day, could you locate it quicker? You shouldn't need to go through 3 days worth of activity if you go to the exact day. Thanks for your explanation and helping me understand.

Comment: Myactivity only saves the searches.  So by April 18th I was just typing in the address in the browser bar and letting the autofill fill out the rest of the address.  I was not using Chrome Google to find the website at that point.  I would have to go back and find the first time that I searched for the website with Google and visited it which was sometime in March but trying to find that in Google activity might take 3 hours and I think I can find it faster if I could figure out how to get Chrome to use the files I have saved on time machine.

Comment: I see the problem. If you remember anything about the title or a glimmer of what the site is called, you could always filter between March to April 18 and use the Search field to narrow down the results. But understandably, this is not the quickest method. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 1):

On MacOS (OS X), the location of Google Chrome history is in the following location:

> ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/History

- NOTE: The **~/** should take you to the *users* library, not the system.

Source: [MacRumors](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/where-does-chrome-store-history.1029029/)

In Windows, the location of Google Chrome history is in the following location:

> C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default

Source: [Google Chrome Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/6ndeqflOq0M)

You may be able to find a program that can extract the data from the SQLite file. This will save you the hassle of creating another user profile and potentially having errors.

Alternatively, as you suggested in your opening question, you may need to:

1. Create a copy of the backed up history files from your current account.
2. Create a new user account.
3. Open Chrome on the new account and browse. This will create the required basic files.
4. Replace the history files that were created in step 3 with the backup files that you got in step 1.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help.  I was able to find the website.  I had looked in myactivity before for the date of april 17th before and did not find anything but the second time I looked I did find a google search called 'linguists search engine' and that took me to the website.